# Data to long for column when shorter than set length

Tags: mysql, sql, char

I have been using this table for some time now with no problems however I recently needed to make the `MouldID` column longer. It had a length of 5 and I have now changed it to 12. However whenever I upload data that has a length of more than 5 I get the error

> Data too long for column MouldID

I have done SHOW COLUMNS (pasted below) and that shows the length as 12 but it acts as if its still 5. Any ideas?

```
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | char(12) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| DateCast  | date     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MouldID   | char(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Litronic  | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SlumpFlow | int(5)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CubeRef   | char(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 9Day      | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 28Day     | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 28Day2    | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 56Day     | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ProdRun   | char(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Schmidt   | int(3)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NWK       | char(7)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AirTemp   | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ConcTemp  | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wcRatio   | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CubeTaken | char(5)  | YES  |     | False   |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What do you mean "whenever I upload data", how is that data imported? Probably the import runs its own checks on the data and hasn't been given the news about the new column size.

Comment: Any trigger associated with that column?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Not an answer, but consider storing a numeric id for both id and mouldid. Consider a DECIMAL data type for all the FLOAT types provided, and separate out the compressive strength tests into a separate table. Oh, and cubetaken could be tinyint (a simple flag with values 1 or 0)

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Thank you, i feel like a moron now. I had a trigger that was filling in another table with similar data and that had a length of 5 on MouldID. Needed to change that also.

Comment: @Strawberry why is a DECIMAL better than a FLOAT in this situation?

Comment: It might not be - I just wanted you to be aware that there is an alternative to FLOAT, which *may* be more appropriate. Also, note that value in parentheses after `INT` is almost meaningless in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Jus try Switch your MySQL mode to not use STRICT.

[some doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)

To change the mode

This can be done in follow way:

Open your "my.ini" file within the MySQL installation directory, and look for the text "sql-mode".
Find:

```
Code:# Set the SQL mode to strict -> sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Replace

```
Code:# Set the SQL mode to strict -> sql mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: Did not work, confirmed that sql_mode was set with mysql -uroot -p -e "select @@sql_mode" Returned:

    +--------------------------------------------+
    | @@sql_mode                                 |
    +--------------------------------------------+
    | NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
    +--------------------------------------------+

Comment: This answer is, "Don't fix the problem, just tell MySQL to silently change your transactional data for you!"  You're telling the system to *ignore* errors instead of fixing the errors.